# Skype is auto increasing volume

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, skype, microphone

Ok I have an odd issue going on here. Skype keeps increasing my volume despite having automatically adjust microphone settings unchecked.

I have unchecked give applications exclusive control in sound properties. I have also disabled all enhancements and it still does it.

Windows 8.1
builtin mic

Comment: I notice this while using skype with a Jabra wireless headset on win7, it does not happen consistently